# problem regarding the way asp.mvc handles database parent-child relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I'm an mvc newbe.
I have a problem regarding the way asp.mvc handles database parent-child relationships.
I have three tables 'Company', 'Member' and 'Method'. I have created a parent/child relationship between 'Company' and 'Member', and a parent/child relationship between 'Member' and 'Method'.
I am using Linq to Sql and a repository pattern to comunicate with my mssql database.

In my HomeController I have the following Action Result

```
var memData = _repository.GetCompany(id);  
return View(memData);
```

In my View I then want to use three partial views

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("ShowCompany"); %>  
<% Html.RenderPartial("ShowMember"); %>  
<% Html.RenderPartial("ShowMethod"); %>
```

I have been able to create the first two partial views and use the following code to iterate over each of the class properties.

```
foreach(Member m in Model.Members)  
  foreach(Company c in Model.Company)
```

Because Members is a child of Company I can iterate over the Members navigation property within the Model.
However, I cannot access the third 'Method' table in the Company Model.
In the context of the Company class, I presume that though 'Method' is a child of 'Member', though not a child of 'Company', that a navigational property is not exposed in the same was as for the 'Member' class?

Can you please advise how I should proceed?
Should I create a custom view model that contained two propertys 'Company and 'Method'?
How would I achieve this? I presume that in my home Controller I would have as well as my first repository method an additional method to retieve a 'Method' object

```
var memData = _repository.GetCompany(id);  
var methodData = _repository.GetMethod(id);
```

How would I pass these two objects into the View()?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use a nested foreach loop

```
foreach (m in model.Members)
{
     //do stuff
     foreach (method in m.Methods)
     {
         //do stuff
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response - this nested for loop is the answer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So to clarify:

Company (has many) Member (has many) Method?

> I presume that though 'Method' is a
>   child of 'Member', though not a child
>   of 'Company', that a navigational
>   property is not exposed in the same
>   was as for the 'Member' class?

If this is the case, and you are missing a navigation property between Company and Member, then you need to create one. Assuming you are using the L2S designer to generate your model, make sure you have the relationship defined in your database.

Once this is done we can move forward.

Then you can interate your collections like so:

```
// model is IEnumerable<Company>

foreach (var company in Model) {
    // do something with company
    foreach (var member in company.Members) {
        // do something with member
        foreach (var method in member.Methods) {
            // do something with method
        }
    }   
}
```